# Raw SQL and file transformation in airflow

Tags: airflow

I am brand new to airflow. I need to run raw postgreSQL script to create a file and make changes to the file using python code in single workflow. How can I make this happen?
Thanks!

Comment: You can start here..Nice beginner's tutorial provided by Mark Litwintschik http://tech.marksblogg.com/airflow-postgres-redis-forex.html